# HttpURLConnection downloaded file name

Tags: java, http, inputstream, httpurlconnection

Is it possible to get the name of a file downloaded with HttpURLConnection?

```
URL url = new URL("http://somesite/getFile?id=12345");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

In the example above I cannot extract the file name from the URL, but the server will send me the file name in some way.

Comment: Fantastic question.Whenever we try to identify the file name obtained while exercising url request on the fly,this use case will be significant...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use [HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(String name)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29) to get the `Content-Disposition` header, which is normally used to set the file name:

```
String raw = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
// raw = "attachment; filename=abc.jpg"
if(raw != null && raw.indexOf("=") != -1) {
    String fileName = raw.split("=")[1]; //getting value after '='
} else {
    // fall back to random generated file name?
}
```

As other answer pointed out, the server might return invalid file name, but you could try it.

Comment: Thanks, this particular server appear to be sending Content-Disposition for every file requested via get parameters. For direct links I will just parse the url.

Comment: After fetching the filename from the header, From where to download that file? Where will be the file? Please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: @Dharmendra You can use [URLConnection.getInputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()) to get the input stream and write to file.

Comment: @PauKiatWee Thanks for your reply. Is URLConnection or similar class available for Javascript(I am implementing this functionality for titanium)

Comment: slight modification to your answer `String fileName = raw.split("=")[1];`

Comment: Blindly getting whatever comes after the "=" is going to fail.

Answer (score 4):

The frank answer is - unless the web server returns the filename in the Content-Disposition header, there isn't a real filename. Maybe you could set it to the URI's last portion after the /, and before the query string.

```
Map m =conn.getHeaderFields();
if(m.get("Content-Disposition")!= null) {
 //do stuff
}
```

Comment: The server is sending the filename in some way, in fact if I use the same link on a web browser I'm offered to save the file and it does have a name.

I just don't know how to fetch it.

Comment: Well, then i'm sure the below snippet will help!

Answer (score 0):

Check for the `Content-Disposition`: attachment header in the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map map = connection.getHeaderFields ();
            if ( map.get ( "Content-Disposition" ) != null )
            {
                String raw = map.get ( "Content-Disposition" ).toString ();
                // raw = "attachment; filename=abc.jpg"
                if ( raw != null && raw.indexOf ( "=" ) != -1 )
                {
                    fileName = raw.split ( "=" )[1]; // getting value after '='
                    fileName = fileName.replaceAll ( "\"", "" ).replaceAll ( "]", "" );
                }
            }
```