# Download Image with the same file name

Tags: android, file, android-asynctask

I have a code below.

```
final URL url1 = stringToURL("linki_of_image/image1.jpg");
final URL url2 = stringToURL("linki_of_image/image2.jpg");
final URL url3 = stringToURL("linki_of_image/image3.jpg");
final URL url4 = stringToURL("linki_of_image/image4.jpg");
final URL url5 = stringToURL("linki_of_image/image5.jpg");

mMyTask = new DownloadTask().execute(url1, url2, url3, url4,url5);

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, List<Bitmap>> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mProgressDialog.show();
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(0);
    }

    protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        List<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            URL currentURL = urls[i];

            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) currentURL.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInputStream);
                bitmaps.add(bmp);

                publishProgress((int) (((i + 1) / (float) count) * 100));
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return bitmaps;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Task cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        mLLayout.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = result.get(i);
            Uri imageInternalUri = saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap, i);
            addNewImageViewToLayout(bitmap);
            addNewImageViewToLayout(imageInternalUri);
        }
    }
}


protected URL stringToURL(String urlString) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        return url;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

protected Uri saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmap, int index) {
    File file = sdCardDirectory;
    file = new File(file, "UniqueFileName" + index + ".jpg");

    try {
        OutputStream stream = null;
        stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
    return savedImageURI;
}

protected void addNewImageViewToLayout(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 500);
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    mLLayout.addView(iv);
}

protected void addNewImageViewToLayout(Uri uri) {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    iv.setImageURI(uri);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 300);
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    mLLayout.addView(iv);
}
```

The code above downloads an image from a server and it work perfectly my only problem here is when it downloads the image the code renames it.

My question is how can i download or create the image still with the same file name (because i noticed that the image is being created)

because the part `saveImageToInternalStorage` renames it into a new file

Comment: And why can't you change that? What's the problem?

Comment: actually i don`t know where to start because this is the first time i made it. All i need is to download the file without renaming it

Answer (score 0):

```
String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName("linki_of_image/image1.jpg");
```

> baseName = image1

```
String baseNameWithExtension = FilenameUtils.getName("linki_of_image/image1.jpg");
```

> baseNameWithExtension = image1.jpg

to answer your question;

My question is how can i download those image without renaming it? **or giving new name just the same on the link**.

```
File file = sdCardDirectory;
file = new File(file, baseNameWithExtension);
```

Comment: Ok i get it sir. Downloading the image needs to rename it. I want to download it as same as the filename of that image

Comment: sir where can i add those code on the code i posted?

Comment: above code doing exactly what you want, it gets file name from link and save file with that name and extension. what you want is not possible because you are creating file with "new File()" and you have to provide one name by yourself

Comment: Just after saveImageToInternalStorage method, you have to apply download link to that method also to use getName method
String baseNameWithExtension = FilenameUtils.getName("linki_of_image/image1.jpg");
File file = sdCardDirectory;
file = new File(file, baseNameWithExtension);

Comment: Whoo.. im very bad at this one.. i didnt see that it creates a new file so a name is needed i just wanted is creating a new file with the same name

Comment: i hope you can help me with this one

Comment: i dont know where to put that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185815/discussion-between-murat-varol-and-myown-email).

Answer (score 0):

Basically the server will give you the name of the file too, you just have to get it from the header and apply it on saving it instead of using your unique name logic

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10995501/4804264

This answer will help you